# Create a new array containing zeros and ones depending one the values in another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy `arrayA`:

```
array([[ 1.],
       [ 7.],
       [ 2.],
       [ 9.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 4.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 4.],
       [ 8.]])
```

And now I want to create another numpy array (`arrayB`) with a width of 10 and a default cell value of 0. Now check `arrayA` row by row take the value as row index for `arrayB` and set the value on 1.

arrayB should look like this for example:

```
[[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
 [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
 [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]]
```

### What can I do to solve this?

The reason why I do this:
I have a neural network and `arrayA` holds the categories for each input pattern (the real array has 25010 rows). But I want 10 output neurons (one for each category) so I need an array for every pattern with nine 0's and a 1 at the right category.

Comment: You've just described the algorithm yourself. Just translate it into Python, that's not so difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using [advanced integer indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing). However you need to convert your array to integers first and remove the second dimension:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> # preprocess your array
>>> arr = np.array([[1.], [7.], [2.], [9.], [0.], [4.], [1.], [4.], [8.]])
>>> arr = arr.astype(int)[:, 0]
>>> # create a result array
>>> new = np.zeros((arr.shape[0], 10), int)
>>> new[np.arange(arr.shape[0]), arr] = 1  # advanced indexing
>>> new
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
```